# Nest div tag override parent div tags property

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage where the contents are centered. It has lot of css and js jinja2 template. When I add a simple div tag

```
   <div class="container"> 
  <!-- something -->
   <div>hello</div>
```

The message is centered too. I tried to change few things but I'm afraid it might it affect some other page too. So I would like to know whether I can force this div tag to get left aligned . I tried 'float=left' is not working. Is possible override all other setting just for this one `<div>` tag?

The page layout is like

```
      Space       |text stats here|  Space
                  |text2          |
```

And expected result:

```
      Space       |text stats here|  Space
                  |text2          |  
      hello
```

DEMO:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/wnfmebyb

Code

```
   <title>test</title>
  <body class="">
     <div class="container">
     <h2> Center Header  </h2>
     centered text
       <br/>
           <div style="float:left"> Wanted this on left </div>
       </div>
        <div style="float:left"> Expected output: LEFT </div>
      </body>
```

css file:

```
.container {
  width: 740px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: How about `text-align:right;`?

Comment: Try adding !important; like this `float:left !important;` as a test to see if it is a specificity issue?

Comment: Thanks for the comments . Let me check

Comment: In HTML a comment tag is like this `<!-- Something -->`

Comment: do you mean that you have text alignment center or you have a div (container) that is centered and text is align left? and you want to put a div on the left of the container div?

Comment: @TasosK , MyStream  No, they didn't work. Pls see above EDIT. Koko, I think container itself is centered. I would like to somehow escape that alignment for second div tag.

Answer (score 2):

add an id to the particular div so you don't have to override any other settings like this -

```
<div class="container"> 
   //something
   <div id="some_id">hello</div>
```

than add **CSS**

```
    #some_id{
        text-align: left !important;
    }
```

Comment: No, the output is similar to '<div style="float:left !important;">' . Text doesn't appear on left-most side of the page.

Comment: seeing your expected result its not a text-align issue.. please post your code to check for nesting of elements, padding, margins etc..

Comment: thanks, will try to post the code on jsfiddle and update the link

Comment: Pls find the code above. When I place div tag outside container its proper. When it is nested the text becomes centered

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to provide 'absolute position' something like below seems to work:

```
<div class="movethis"> Wanted this on left </div>

.movethis{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Result : http://cssdeck.com/labs/4rtflvmy